# The array of objects displayed in the p-table is not displayed in original order when row grouping

Tags: angular, primeng, webpack-3, typescript2.4, primeng-turbotable

The array of objects displayed in the p-table(TurboTable) is not displayed in original order when **row grouping**.

The data sent to the table are note rendered in exact order

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  cars: any[];
  sales: any[];

   ngOnInit() {
  this.cars =[
    {"vin":"AAA","brand":"VW","year":1998,"color":"White","price":10000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"Mercedes","year":1985,"color":"Green","price":25000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"Jaguar","year":1979,"color":"Silver","price":30000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"Audi","year":1970,"color":"Black","price":12000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"Volvo","year":1992,"color":"Red","price":15500},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"VW","year":1993,"color":"Maroon","price":40000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"Fiat","year":1964,"color":"Blue","price":25000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"Renault","year":1983,"color":"Maroon","price":22000},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"Renault","year":1961,"color":"Black","price":19000},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"Audi","year":1984,"color":"Brown","price":36000},
{"vin":"CCC","brand":"VW","year":1984,"color":"Silver","price":215000},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"Volvo","year":1987,"color":"Silver","price":32000},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"Jaguar","year":1995,"color":"Maroon","price":20000},
{"vin":"CCC","brand":"Jaguar","year":1984,"color":"Orange","price":14000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"Honda","year":1989,"color":"Maroon","price":36000},
{"vin":"AAA","brand":"BMW","year":1986,"color":"Blue","price":28000},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"Mercedes","year":1986,"color":"Orange","price":14000},
{"vin":"CCC","brand":"Mercedes","year":1991,"color":"White","price":25000},
{"vin":"DDD","brand":"VW","year":1992,"color":"Blue","price":36000},
{"vin":"CCC","brand":"Renault","year":2001,"color":"Blue","price":25000},
{"vin":"DDD","brand":"Jaguar","year":1990,"color":"Yellow","price":52000},
{"vin":"CCC","brand":"Audi","year":1966,"color":"Maroon","price":45000},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"BMW","year":1962,"color":"Blue","price":54000},
{"vin":"BBB","brand":"Honda","year":1982,"color":"Blue","price":22000},
{"vin":"DDD","brand":"Mercedes","year":2003,"color":"Silver","price":15000},
{"vin":"EEE","brand":"Mercedes","year":1986,"color":"White","price":18000},
{"vin":"CCC","brand":"BMW","year":1983,"color":"Brown","price":32000},
{"vin":"EEE","brand":"VW","year":1973,"color":"Maroon","price":36000},
{"vin":"FFFF","brand":"Mercedes","year":1991,"color":"Red","price":21000}
];
}

onSort() {
        this.updateRowGroupMetaData();
    }

    updateRowGroupMetaData() {
        this.rowGroupMetadata = {};
        if (this.cars) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
                let rowData = this.cars[i];
                let brand = rowData.brand;
                if (i == 0) {
                    this.rowGroupMetadata[brand] = { index: 0, size: 1 };
                }
                else {
                    let previousRowData = this.cars[i - 1];
                    let previousRowGroup = previousRowData.brand;
                    if (brand === previousRowGroup)
                        this.rowGroupMetadata[brand].size++;
                    else
                        this.rowGroupMetadata[brand] = { index: i, size: 1 };
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**html**

```
<p-table [value]="cars" sortField="brand" sortMode="single" (onSort)="onSort()">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Vin</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <tr class="ui-widget-header" *ngIf="rowGroupMetadata[rowData.brand].index === rowIndex">
            <td colspan="3">
                <span style="font-weight:bold">{{rowData.brand}}</span>
            </td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{rowData.vin}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.year}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.color}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**plunker**

> **https://plnkr.co/edit/DUhP4a4dMLZUmEjmBkok?p=preview**

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650472/how-to-sort-data-in-a-primeng-datatable-with-row-grouping

Comment: @Antikhippe the link is for prime DataTable. I have used TurboTable check for the plunker.

Comment: Yes but it is exactly the same problem : you have to create a custom filter.

Comment: @Antikhippe in the table i need to display the order by brand & vin. In that rowgroup  based on brand i need to order vin field.

Comment: @Antikhippe i need to show data in order by brand & vin EX: Audi is first brand group in that group i need to show VIN in order like AAA,BBB,CCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in comments, you should use a custom sort method to sort by *brand* then by *vin* :

```
customSort(e) {
    this.cars.sort(function (a, b) {
      let aGroup = a.brand.toLowerCase();
      let bGroup = b.brand.toLowerCase();
      if (aGroup > bGroup) return 1;
      if (aGroup < bGroup) return -1;
      let aSort = a.vin.toLowerCase();
      let bSort = b.vin.toLowerCase();
      if (aSort > bSort) return 1;
      if (aSort < bSort) return -1;
      return 0
    });
  }
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HbNyCTXB5eXYO1uQcM7z?p=preview)